# Arduino LCD Display não exibe mensagem

Tags: arduino

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o simulador https://www.tinkercad.com.

Não estou conseguindo fazer aparece a mensagem de teste no display. Ao ligar não aparece mensagem, apenas liga o display.

O que estou fazendo errado?

*Não se atentar ao demais componentes, apenas a mensagem de teste a ser exibida no LCD.*

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int temperatura = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(9,8,5,4,3,2);

void setup()
{
  //Confg LCD
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Teste");

  //Senssor temp
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);

  //LEDs
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  temperatura = analogRead(A0);
  if (temperatura >= -40 || temperatura <= 15) {
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  if (temperatura >= 16 || temperatura <= 23) {
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  if (temperatura >= 24 || temperatura <= 125) {
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }


  //LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Teste 2");



  //delay(10); // Delay a little bit to improve simulation performance
}
```

Comment: @Maniero, o que você não entendeu?

Comment: A pergunta tem apenas que você tem um problema, e um código solto, ninguém nem sabe o que deveria ser o certo, como sabe que dá problema, o que tentou resolver, porque acha que não deu certo. Coloque informações que ajudem as pessoas te ajudarem, essas pessoas entendem menos que você do seu problema, precisa explicá-lo de forma completa.